# How do I check for a win in a tic tac toe game?

Tags: python, image, if-statement, button

I've seen how to check for a win on tic tac toe games, but I am using images and I can't seem to figure out how. I thought of using if statements and having 3 buttons equal the image that is shown, but that doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

```
from tkinter import*

#Window stuff   
window = Tk()
window.title("Tic Tac Toe")
window.configure(background = "black")
window.geometry("400x400")

#Variables
global clickable
playerXturn = True

#Display X or O
def buttonClicked(c) : 
    global playerXturn
    if playerXturn == True :
        buttonList[c]["image"] = picX
        playerXturn = False
        labelTurn ["text"] = "O's turn"

    elif clickable[c] == "" : 
        buttonList[c]["image"] = picO
        playerXturn = True
        labelTurn ["text"] = "X's turn"
#Check for a win
    if button1 == picX and button2 == picX and button3 == picX:
        print("r") 

#Images
picX = PhotoImage (file = "x.gif") 
picO = PhotoImage (file = "o.gif")
picBlank = PhotoImage (file = "sw.gif") 

#Buttons
button1 = Button (window, text = "", image = picBlank, command = lambda: buttonClicked(0))     
button1.grid (row = 0, column = 0)
#button1["state"] = DISABLED 
button2 = Button (window, text = "", image = picBlank, command = lambda: buttonClicked(1))    
button2.grid (row = 0, column = 1)
#button2["state"] = DISABLED 
button3 = Button (window, text = "", image = picBlank, command = lambda: buttonClicked(2))  
button3.grid (row = 0, column = 2)
#button3["state"] = DISABLED 
button4 = Button (window, text = "", image = picBlank, command = lambda: buttonClicked(3))   
button4.grid (row = 1, column = 0)
#button4["state"] = DISABLED 
button5 = Button (window, text = "", image = picBlank,  command = lambda: buttonClicked(4)) 
button5.grid (row = 1, column = 1)
#button5["state"] = DISABLED 
button6 = Button (window, text = "", image = picBlank,  command = lambda: buttonClicked(5))  
button6.grid (row= 1, column = 2)
#button6["state"] = DISABLED 
button7 = Button (window, text = "", image = picBlank, command = lambda: buttonClicked(6)) 
button7.grid (row = 2, column = 0)
#button7["state"] = DISABLED 
button8 = Button (window, text = "", image = picBlank, command = lambda: buttonClicked(7))   
button8.grid (row = 2, column = 1)
#button8["state"] = DISABLED 
button9 = Button (window, text = "", image = picBlank, command = lambda: buttonClicked(8))  
button9.grid (row = 2, column = 2)
#button9["state"] = DISABLED 

#Labels
labelTurn = Label (window, text = "",) 
labelTurn.grid (row = 4, column = 4)

#Lists
buttonList = [button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6, button7, button8, button9]
clickable = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Probable duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33178684/python-programming-3-4-2-naughts-and-crosses-best-way-to-check-how-to-see-if-g/33179368#33179368

Answer (score 0):

You can use a 2-Dimentional list to store the values of the buttons ("X", "O" or None). After that you should check the rows, columns and diagonals.

List example:

```
table = [[0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0]]
```

You can do the check in the main loop, but you can also do the check in each click handler so the unnecessary CPU work would be saved.

After Creating the list, in the checking function you can use implementations like;

```
for row in table:
    if set(row) == set("X"):
        # "X"s win condition
```

like so...